# Xrandr showing screen without current/active resolution

Tags: debian, xrandr

I have 2 screens attached to my pc. One over HDMI and one over DisplayPort.

When I execute xrandr (v1.5.0), the screen connected via display port has no active resolution (it's also in standby, with the right input selected).

When I restart xinit, the screen becomes active...

I wonder in what circumstances this can happen and what this actually means when a screen has no active mode? Is killing xinit the best way to solve this?

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   3840x2160     60.00 +  29.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2048x1280     59.99  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Do you have two monitors connected, or just one? If just one, what is DP1 connected to? Is it e.g. a Laptop with an external Monitor?

Comment: @dirkt I added more context to the question.

Comment: So what happens if you just set an active resolution on `DP1 with `xrandr`? What does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` say about how it ended up in that situation? Is your intention to use the monitors side-by-side?